# Display AVCaptureDepthDataOutput as a 3d mesh

Tags: swift, 3d, mesh

I am playing around with AVCaptureDepthDataOutput and I found wonderful sample from WDC'17 with Wiggle app - It displays 3d mesh created from depth data from a portrait camera mode on dual lenses iPhones.

However it's in ObjC, do you maybe happened to have any sample that works in Swift ?

Here's link: https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Using-Depth-Data.zip